# ActiveRecord method decrement! updates other attributes as well. Why is that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a basic authentication system just like in Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#sec:remember_me). Basically, a remember token is stored in a cookie. I implemented Ryan Bate's [Beta-Invitations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations) from Railscast #124, where you can send a limited number of invitations. While doing that, I ran into the problem that [the current user got logged out after sending an invitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064057/rails-mailer-has-issues-with-session-persistence-and-with-sending-email). This was caused by this code in the invitation model:

invitation.rb

```
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
[...]
before_create :decrement_sender_count, :if => :sender
[...]
def decrement_sender_count
  sender.decrement! :invitation_limit
end
```

In the logs I saw that sender.decrement! not only updated the invitation_limit but the remember_token as well:

```
UPDATE "users" SET "invitation_limit" = 9982, "remember_token" = 'PYEWo_om0iaMjwltU4iRBg', "updated_at" = '2012-07-06 09:57:43.354922' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
```

I found an [ugly workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11359742/422656) but I would love to know what the problem really is. Since I don't know where to start, I'll show you the update method from the users controller. What else could be relevant?

users_controller.rb

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = t('success.profile_save')
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash.now[:error] = t('error.profile_save')
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decrement!` calls `save` which of course fires save callbacks. It looks like the book directs you to do

```
before_save :create_remember_token
def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```

which means that saving a user will always invalidate the remember token. I assume this is so that when a user changes their password the remember token changes too, but it means that there is obviously some collateral damage.

You could use the `decrement_counter` which in essence does

```
update users set counter_name = counter_name - 1 where id =12345
```

without running any callbacks. This also avoids some race condition scenarios. However changing the token whenever the user changes is bound to change the token at times when you don't expect it - you might want to only change it when relevant (perhaps when credentials have changed)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you're experiencing a common pitfall in ActiveRecord update methods:

Having a look at ActiveRecord documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/decrement!) you can see the actual implementation of the decrement! method:

```
def decrement!(attribute, by = 1)
  decrement(attribute, by).update_attribute(attribute, self[attribute])
end
```

The interesting part is the update_attribute which is called upon the self object - although the method implies ActiveRecord will only update the specified attribute, it really updates all dirty attributes of the self object.

That means that if, at any point, you change the remember token attribute of the object, it will be saved to the DB during the update_attributes call.

If I'm right and that's the problem - just make sure no changes are made to the remember_token attribute at runtime.

Other than that you may consider using [ActiveRecord's update_column](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) method which will update a single column on the DB without performing the save method on the object